# How to avoid duplicates on ManyToMany relation with Doctrine2 and Zend Framework2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, duplicates, many-to-many, zend-framework2

The objective is to have 2 entity Article and Tag, with a many to many relation where the tags in Tag Table remain unique even if declare the same tag for other article.
I try to explain better with code:

Article Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles") 
 */
class Article {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var int 
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag\Entity\Tag",inversedBy="platforms",cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * 
     * @return Tag[]
     */
    protected $tags;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setTags($tags){
        $this->tags = $tags;
    }

    public function setTagsFromArray(array $tags){
        foreach($tags as $tag){
            $this->tags->add(new Tag($tag));
        }        
    }

    /**
     * Return the associated Tags
     * 
     * @param boolean $getOnlyTagsName [optional] If set to true return a simple array of string (tags name). 
     * If set to false return array of Tag objects. 
     * 
     * @return Tag[]|string[] 
     */
    public function getTags($getOnlyTagsName=false) {
        if ($getOnlyTagsName){
            return array_map(function($i) { return $i->getName(); }, $this->tags->toArray());
        }

        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function addTags($tags) {
        foreach($tags as $tag){
            $this->tags->add($tag);
        }
    }

    public function removeTags($tags) {
        foreach ($tags as $tag){
            $this->tags->removeElement($tag);        
        }
    }  
}
```

Tag Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tags")
 * ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks // NOT USED
 */
class Tag {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",unique=true)
     * @var string 
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime",name="created_at")
     * @var datetime 
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime",name="updated_at")
     * @var datetime 
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article\Entity\Article", mappedBy="tags")
     * var Tag[] 
     */
    protected $platforms;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string $name Tag's name
     */
    public function __construct($name = null) {
        $this->setName($name);
        $this->setCreatedAt(new DateTime('now'));
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new DateTime('now'));
    }

    /**
     * Avoid duplicate entries.
     * 
     * ORM\PrePersist // NOT USED
     */
    public function onPrePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {

    }

    /**
     * Avoid duplicate entries.
     * 
     * ORM\PreUpdate  // NOT USED
     */
    public function onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args) {
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * Returns tag's id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the tag's name
     *
     * @param string $name Name to set
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Returns tag's name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(DateTime $date) {
        $this->createdAt = $date;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt() {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(DateTime $date) {
        $this->updatedAt = $date;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt() {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }    
}
```

Then I have the Article Form (with Article Fieldset) where there is a tagsinput (jquery plugin) element. So the form post it's like:

```
object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)[151]
  public 'security' => string 'dc2a6ff900fbc87933e07bd35ef36709...' (length=65)
  public 'article' => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '' (length=0)
      'name' => string 'Article 1' (length=13)
      'tags' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'tag1' (length=3)
          1 => string 'tag2' (length=4)
          2 => string 'tag3' (length=7)
  public 'submit' => string 'Add' (length=8)
```

A the first insert all goes well, but when I try to insert another article with one of the article1 tags I get the error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO tags (name, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["tag2", "2014-04-26 22:05:37", "2014-04-26 22:05:37"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'tag2' for key 'UNIQ_6FBC94265E237E06'
```

I know that I can use prePersist and preUpdate event listner, but I made some test but I don't know how to use Unit Of Work to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the **Tag**'s **name** property (and database field) defined as **unique**. You'll have the *Integrity constraint violation* every time you set a new tag with a previously picked tag name. You just need to control that a name is not picked for a tag related to the same article.

You could add a **[Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.db.html)** validator to the **tagsinput** element to achieve that. It would be something like that:

```
$tagsinput->getValidatorChain()->addValidator(
    new NoRecordExists( array(
    'adapter' => $this->getServiceManager()->get( 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' ),
    'table' => 'tag',
    'field' => 'name',
    'message' => 'The tag name already exists', 
    'exclude' => 'article_id = ' . $article->getId(),
) );
```

--

**Edit:**
This solution won't work if there are more than one tag, when **tagsinput**'s value will be an array. You could iterate through the array to validate each tag, but it's not an efficient solution, it would execute **N** queries. You could implement a similar validator which accepts a where clause like **TAG_NAME IN ( 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3' )**

--

Note that this validator doesn't work with Doctrine2; **table**, **field** and **exclude** parameters have database values.

This should work when adding tags to an existing article. To validate that a new article doesn't have duplicated tags, you could do it client side or you could [write your own validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.writing-validators.html).

Comment: Thanks but, with some help, I found the solution by changing `setTagsFromArray` function to check if the tag already exists.